# What's the equivalent of NSOperationQueue in java android?

Tags: java, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I love nsoperationqueue in iOS. What's the equivalent in java?

Comment: DO you know the use of NSOperationQueue?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Lars Vogel has a nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools).